# MySQL left join table to itself

Tags: mysql, join

I've been driving myself crazy on this, but I've gotten as far as I think I can.

I have a table with a list of users and their groups (this is a middle table between the user table and the group table).

I need to be able to select users who are in one group but NOT in another group.

I know I am not supposed to use != during the "on" because it hangs forever, but I can't figure out what kind of join to use.

For example I want to pick all users who are in the "mod_group" but who are not in the "admin_group".

I've simplified this example down, but yes I'm aware their may appear to be another way to do this. Unfortunately rewriting elsewhere likely isn't an option, so I'm hoping to find a solution this way.

EDIT: adding table to make it more clear

This is the Middle Table

```
| data_user | data_group |
+-----------+------------+
|     1     |     1      |
|     1     |     2      |
|     2     |     2      |
|     3     |     1      |
|     3     |     2      |
|     4     |     2      |
|     5     |     1      |
```

The expected result would be to return users 2 and 4 if I'm looking for those who are in group2 but not group1

It needs to be dynanmic, so I could do the opposite(look for users who are in group1 but not group2, which would return user5)

Comment: Add your table schema and some testable records

Comment: Post your table for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your table structure is something along the lines of the following:

**middle table**

```
user_id | group_id
```

**group table**

```
id | name
```

**user table**

```
id | username
```

You can use conditional aggregation over users in the `middle_table` to identify users who were in the `mod_group` but are not in the `admin_group`:

```
SELECT t3.username
FROM middle_table t1
INNER JOIN group_table t2
    ON t1.group_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN user_table t3
    ON t1.user_id = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.name = 'mod_group'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.name = 'admin_group' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: I thought this might be the right thing, but when I tried it, it came back with an empty set (when I know for a fact that there are users in the mod group who are not in the admin group). I updated the original post to give a better sample of the middle table and expected output.

I'm not worried about the group_table and user_table, I know how to do those joins. It's the going over the middle table to find users only on one list but not the other that I'm struggling with.

cheers

Comment: I believe this query should work without problems.  Please post some sample data if possible.